# Finding a function g such that $\int_0^3 f(x) dx = C\int_a^b g(x) dx$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

> Let $f:[0,3]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let  $\int_0^3 f(x) dx $ exist. Find a function g such that $\int_0^3 f(x) dx = C\int_a^b g(x) dx$.

I'm not sure what I am supposed to do to solve the problem. Do I need to use one of the four rules : rectangle rule, trapezoidal rule, Gaussian quadrature or the Simpson's rule ? And what about the error ?

Comment: Hint: Substitute $g=f\circ \phi$ and determine $\phi$ to match the boundaries.

Comment: Change variable $u=a+\dfrac{b-a}{3}x$ in left integral.

Comment: $$\int_0^3 f(x) dx = F(3) -F(0) =C\int_a^b g(x) dx = C\int_a^b f(\phi(x)) dx = C\int_a^b f(\phi(x))\phi^{-1}(x)\phi(x) dx=C\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(z)\phi^{-1}(z)dz$$ How do I solve the integral from here on?

Comment: And sorry I don't get the 2nd tip ...

Comment: I mean $ C\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(z)(\phi^{-1})'(z)dz$